# A little problem in geometry

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, geometry

Suppose $A$ is a compact set in $\mathbb{R}^n, n\geq 2$ and it has measure zero with $0\not\in A$, can we find a line $L\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ passing through the origin which intersects $A$ in a finite number of points?

Comment: Why not consider the set $A=\{(x,x)\in\Bbb R^2:\, 1\leq x\leq 2\}$? If a line passing through the origin intersects $A$ at all, it necessarily contains $A$ and therefore intersects $A$ at infinitely many points (unless you don't force the line to be infinite, in which case the question is trivial anyway).

Comment: @Clayton The question is can you always find a line that intersects any such set at finite number of points. Your example does not answer that question.

Comment: @Maesumi: How does it not answer the question? $A$ is compact, has measure zero, doesn't contain the origin, and no line passing through the origin only intersects in a finite number of places.

Comment: As the set is compact it is bounded and so if you were free to choose a line then you could choose it so that it does not cross any  point of the set (or its convex hull). The requirement of going through origin is just so that the problem becomes interesting. Other wise it plays no other role.

Comment: @Clayton, you are correct. I ask this question because  I want to solve a problem in my homework: let $M^n$ be a compact smooth manifold and let $f: M^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be a smooth map such that $0\not\in f(M)$. Show that we can find a line $L\subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ passing through the origin which intersects $f(M)$ in a finite number of points.

Comment: so this approach does not work.

Comment: Does "finite number of points", requested in question,  include no intersection as well?

Comment: Either, we have two counterexamples in both cases, due to Clayton and CutieKrait below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not consider the set $\{(x,x)\in\Bbb R^2:\, 1\leq x\leq 2\}$?

This set is clearly compact as it is homeomorphic to $[1,2]$, and any line passing through the origin will either contain $A$ (and therefore intersect $A$ in infinitely many points), or not intersect $A$ at all. Thus, it is not always possible to find a line passing through the origin which intersects a compact set at only finitely many points.

It's easy to see how this generalizes to $\Bbb R^n$, so for any dimension, we have a counterexample to the possibility.

Comment: @daniel things were added later on.

Comment: I was wrong, I was imaging a square. The comment is now deleted. My objection now is that 0 is a finite number of points.

Comment: @leo: If that is the only objection, then it is a matter of understanding the question. I took intersecting in $0$ places to not be considered since then it doesn't intersect (matter of phrasing, I suppose).

Comment: Well, one can say that a no intersection is the same as 0 element intersection. It is a question like "is it 0 natural number or isn't? I guess this not the first time this debate occurs :-)

Answer (score 4):

Consider

$$2S^1\cup \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty (2-\frac{1}{k})S^1$$

where $S^1$ is the unit circle for $n=2$. And generally

$$2S^{n-1}\cup \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty (2-\frac{1}{k})S^{n-1}$$

Comment: Thanks, by the way, is the set you defined a compact smooth submanifold in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @ougao: it is compact, because it is bounded and closed. to show closedness show that any convergent sequence converges in the set.

Comment: I also think this should be a smooth compact submanifold, but it is a homework says that: let $M^n$ be a compact smooth manifold and let $f: M^n\to R^{n+1}$ be a smooth map such that $0\not\in f(M)$. Show that we can find a line $L\subset R^{ n+1}$ passing through the origin which intersects $f(M)$  in a finite number of points. If your example works, then it shows this problem is wrong?

Comment: I don't know much about manifolds. However check if connectedness is useful.

Comment: There is no assumption on the connectness in the definition of manifold, maybe I should ask it as another problem.